# Does firebase log metadata such as 'created_at' automatically

Tags: javascript, firebase, logging, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a prototype with Firebase for Web, and I would like to add some data about each database transaction, most importantly the datetimes at which the item is created and updated.

Any chance that Firebase does this as well, and can I retrieve this information with their API?

Let me add to this a question about general analytics. I see Firebase offers Google Analytics for apps, but I guess this is more geared towards frontend use of the app. I am looking for data like:

- When did which user log in and log out?
- Which items did they retrieve from Firebase and when?
- Which items did they add to Firebase and when?

I understand that I could add this to Firebase myself, but I was wondering if Firebase already has a service that offers (part of) this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Database does not automatically store metadata about the timestamp that nodes were created/updated or who performed the operation. If that is needed for you app, you'll have to store the data yourself.