# Firebase last action time in specified location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep a local copy of a simple database in user's phone. This way the app can be used offline. I want to check with firebase server from time to time and update the local database if there is any change. So I need to know last action (insert, update, delete, etc.) time in a specified location in Firebase database. Is that possible? Or should I implement my own mechanism?

Comment: Why do you need to know the time of those actions?

Comment: Firebase does not automatically track such data. Also see the answer that I gave a few hours ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934119/does-firebase-log-metadata-such-as-created-at-automatically/45942021#45942021

Comment: @AlexMamo, I am looking for a way to detect if there is any change, and if there is, retrieve the whole path/table or just the changes.

Comment: Well, it is better to stick offline capabilities of Firebase, thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but you shouldn't

Firebase already has offline capabilities, is very simple to use. Is a 2 steps process:

1. Set offline capabilities on
2. Set what you want to keep track ass offline

This is the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

In code this is done something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

There is big temptation to use:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().keepSynced(true);
```

Trying to keep everything sync by syncing the root reference doesn't work, you have to be specific, at least at 1 level parent.

The syncing when the connection is resumed is automatic, the user has to open the app though, flawless.

Now, if you still insist on doing this, then what you have to do is set `ServeValue.TimeStamp`

In the same link provided above, you can find how to set the server timestamp, here is the [direct reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue).

Later you can sort by that timestamp, here is a more [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45757566/4017501)

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database does not store informations like the timestamp for `CRUD operations` that are performed. Because of that, you need to store this kind of data yourself with your own mechanism. So, you need to create a new field for each child you want to trace and change the value of the `TIMESTAMP` every time a action is performed. The best practice is to save your data as a `TIMESTAMP` like this: `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. Note, that when you are saving the `TIMESTAMP`, you are saving as a `Map` and when you are retrieving, you are retrieving it as a `long`. To set the `TIMESTAMP`, i recomand you using the following code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

To get you data back, i recomand you using the following method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```